# Creating index by concatinating multiple columns MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

I am new to mySQL and trying to migrate to MySQL from oracle and I have an index that I need to convert to mySQL. In oracle I have created this index by using 2 columns as :

```
CREATE INDEX TEST ON TABLE(COL1||'/'||COL2, COL3)
```

Now I am trying to find alternate for this in mySQL. I know that I can create index on multiple columns in my sql like :

```
CREATE INDEX TEST on TABLE(COL1, COL2)
```

But I want to create index on multiple columns such that I can combine COL1 and COL2 using '/' delimiter and create index on it. I Found that I can create a generated column and create index on it. So basically I will have something like this :

```
 CREATE INDEX TEST on TABLE(GENERATED_COL, COL2)
```

when I try to create this generated column I keep getting syntax error for generated column. Here is my syntax to create table :

```
CREATE TABLE PATH (
ID INT(38) NOT NULL,
PATH_PREFIX VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
PATH_SUFFIX VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
FULLPATH VARCHAR(3000) AS (CONCAT(PATH_PREFIX,'/',PATH_SUFFIX)),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

Here is my error :

```
SQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS (CONCAT(PATH_PREFIX,'/',PATH_SUFFIX)),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
```

Not sure if I am doing something wrong here? If this is not right way can someone please advise me on what is the right way of creating index like CONCAT(PATH_PREFIX,'/',PATH_SUFFIX)

Comment: MySql doesn't alow for function-based indexes. You can't do that. You can create an additional column in the table (say `COL_X`), fill it with `CONCAT(PATH_PREFIX,'/',PATH_SUFFIX)` and then create index on this new column. `COL_X`). The other option is to  stay with Oracle, or to migrate to a database that alows for function-based indexes - for exmple PostgreSQL or MS-Sql).

Comment: @kordirko So are you saying create new column and everytime and entry is made to this table have some trigger that will populate this new column with the concatenated value?

Comment: @kordirko from v5.7.6 you can create generated columns. If you set its type to stored, then xou can create secondary indexes on it.

Comment: @Shadow can you please tell more on how I can create this index? I am not sure if I follow your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From mysql v5.7.6 you can create generated columns. If you set its type to stored, then you can create secondary indexes on it. From v5.7.8 you can even create indexes on virtual generated columns, see mysql's documentation on [create table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html):

> As of MySQL 5.7.8, InnoDB supports secondary indexes on virtual
>   generated columns. Other index types are not supported.
>
> A secondary index may be created on one or more virtual columns or on
>   a combination of virtual columns and non-virtual generated columns.
>   Secondary indexes on virtual columns may be defined as UNIQUE.

Comment: Following the syntax mentioned in documentation I updated create table syntax to use " FULLPATH VARCHAR(3000) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CONCAT(PATH_PREFIX,'/',PATH_SUFFIX)) " but I still get the same error. If it is permitted then I am not sure what is causing this error.  Do you see any problem with my create table syntax?

Comment: Check the basics first: the version of your mysql server.